Integral of Bessel Function
I am interested in the following integral:
$$\int_0^L dx\;\frac{J_0(x)}{x}$$
where $J_0(x)$ is a Bessel function of the first kind. Does the integral converge, and if so is there a simple way to write the solution?
I've looked all over and haven't been able to find any information on this specific integral. I have come across an identity for the following integral:
$$\int dx \;\frac{J_0(x)}{x^m}$$
but the solution is undefined for the $m=1$ case (as in, there is a factor of $m-1$ in the denominator of the soltion). I am hoping that this means the identity only applies for $m\neq1$, rather than implying that the $m=1$ solution doesn't exist at all. Would appreciate any help.

This amounts to finding the antiderivative of $J_0(x)/x$ for positive $x$. Mathematica does yield the hypergeometric function $$\int \frac{J_0(x)}{x},dx=x~{1}F_2(1/2;1/2,3/2;-x^2/4)=\sum{n=0}^\infty \frac{ (-1/4)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)(n!)^2}$$ but this presumably amounts to using the series expansion of $J_0(x)/x$ and integrating term-by-term.

It can not exist for $m=1$ since  $J_0(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^4}{64}+O\left(x ^6\right)$

The integral diverges. You can use the inequality
$$ J_0(x) \geq  1- \frac14 x^2$$ to bound the Bessel function from below. With this, you obtain
$$ \int_0^L dx\;\frac{J_0(x)}{x} \geq \int_0^L dx\;\frac{1-\frac14 x^2}{x} = \Bigl(\log x - \frac{1}{8} x^2 \Bigr)\Bigg|_{x=0}^L$$
and the integral is (logarithmically) diverging.

In terms of hypergeometric function,
$$\int \frac{J_0(x)}{x}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\log
   \left(x^2\right)+\gamma-\log(2)-\frac{ x^2}{8} \,
   _2F_3\left(1,1;2,2,2;-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)$$ and
$$ \,_2F_3\left(1,1;2,2,2;t\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{(n+1)^3 \,\,(n!)^2}$$
Remains the problem of the lower bound which cannot be $0$.
